# How incremental OTA works in AB oTA update

Tags: ota-update, aosp

I understood AB OTA work flow in android.
I could not able to understanding, How incremental OTA works in AB update in AOSP.

```
 Full OTA_V0:
 A-->Active state
 B-->Inactive state

 Incremental OTA_V1:
 A-->Inactive state
 B-->Active state

 Incremental OTA_V2:
 A-->Active state(how incremental works here, because this slot is inactive in Incremental OTA_V1 ).
 B-->Inactive state
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A/B (Seamless) update device questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203499/a-b-seamless-update-device-questions)

Comment: The Google documentation is not clear on the combination of incremental OTA updates on A/B devices but I would assume that after applying OTA_v1, changing the slot to B and rebooting after some time the changes from B are also applied to A (or may be the whole partition is copied?). So that the next incremental OTA update can again applied to the inactive partition (plus switch afterwards).

Comment: Related: [How does update_engine validate a differential update-image with dm-verity enabled?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218601/218526)