# Signing TWRP with OpenPGP doesn't work, private key needed?

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader-lock

I am trying to sign TWRP (Redmi Note 8 ginkgo) using GPG on Windows 10. I have imported the TWRP public key, however, when I select the file for signing, it does not show up in the drop-down menu in Kleopatra. From my research, this seems to be due to it being a public key and missing the private key part (correct me if this is wrong please).

I have no idea how to acquire such a key that would allow me to sign TWRP correctly. Could anyone please help me with this?

Additional info:
The bootloader is locked and I don't have TWRP installed. I want to use the command `fastboot boot twrp.img`, however, it doesn't work with a locked bootloader. I get the error `FAILED (remote: Fastboot boot command is not available in locked device)`. I read somewhere that it might work if TWRP was signed without having to unlock the bootloader.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the link. I will have to do more research to understand the information there, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

For correctly signing TWRP you need the device signature private key that only the device manufacturer has.

Therefore it is impossible to sign TWRP for a bootloader locked device.

Furthermore Android images are not PGP signed, therefore a PGP signature would be of no use no matter which key you use.
More details about ROM image signatures can be found here: [Verifying a (custom) ROM signature](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233087/verifying-a-custom-rom-signature)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will be sure to look at the link for more info.