# Disable signature verify in android default bootloader for zip files

Tags: adb, samsung, boot, samsung-galaxy-j7, zip

I have a J7 elte. When I want to sideload a zip file with adb from the phone's default boot loader the bootloader raises error `Signature Verification Failed whole-file`. How can I disable this verification in my phone's default bootloader?

Comment: `adb sideload` is a feature of recovery, not of bootloader. They both are independent environments; tiny operating systems. // "Signature verification failed" cannot be prevented in stock recoveries. They accept ROMs signed by the OEM only. You can install a custom recovery if available and possible. More details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233134/218526

Comment: As I understand I should verify the zip file in my laptop with https://wiki.lineageos.org/verifying-builds way and then again try to sideload. It this true?
I verified the zip file with the above way and again got the error.

Comment: You haven't stated clearly but I assume that you are using stock recovery and trying to flash a 3rd party ZIP file. In this case it's not possible to avoid "Signature verification failed" error in stock recoveries. Stock recoveries accept flashable ZIP files created and signed by the device manufacturer only. To flash other ZIP files (if you know what you are doing) you should install a custom recovery (like TWRP) if one is available for your device, and if it's possible to unlock bootloader on your device (which is a requirement to flash custom ROMs and recoveries).

Comment: If you want to know more about how ZIP signature verification works in recovery and what the error means, please visit [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233134/218526). It's for knowledge only. It won't resolve your problem.

Comment: Finally I could install twrp and my problem solved.